# Can't add new rows to a Gtk::ListBox

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I want add dynamically new *Gtk::ListBoxRow(s)* to a *Gtk::ListBox*, but they don't show up at all. During testing I noticed, that even a simple function isn't able to add a new *Gtk::ListBoxRow*.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Gtk::ListBox* listbox;

void test() {
    Gtk::Label other("other");
    Gtk::Box otherbox;
    otherbox.pack_start(other);
    Gtk::ListBoxRow otherrow;
    otherrow.add(otherbox);
    listbox->append(otherrow);
    // this doesn't help either
    listbox->show_all_children();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "im.lost");

    Gtk::ApplicationWindow window;
    window.set_title("I'm lost");
    window.set_position(Gtk::WIN_POS_CENTER);
    window.set_default_size(600, 400);
    window.set_border_width(10);

    listbox = new Gtk::ListBox();
    listbox->set_selection_mode(Gtk::SELECTION_NONE);

    Gtk::Label foo("foo");
    Gtk::Label fooo("fooo");
    Gtk::Box foobox;
    foobox.pack_start(foo);
    foobox.pack_start(fooo);
    Gtk::ListBoxRow foorow;
    foorow.add(foobox);
    listbox->append(foorow);

    Gtk::Label bar("bar");
    Gtk::Label barr("barr");
    Gtk::Box barbox;
    barbox.pack_start(bar);
    barbox.pack_start(barr);
    Gtk::ListBoxRow barrow;
    barrow.add(barbox);
    listbox->append(barrow);


    Gtk::Label baz("baz");
    Gtk::Label bazz("bazz");
    Gtk::Box bazbox;
    bazbox.pack_start(baz);
    bazbox.pack_start(bazz);
    Gtk::ListBoxRow bazrow;
    bazrow.add(bazbox);
    listbox->append(bazrow);

    test();

    window.add(*listbox);
    window.show_all_children();
    return app->run(window);

}
```

This code can be compiled and run with:

```
g++ -o listbox listbox.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` && ./listbox
```

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `test()`, the widgets that you created are destroyed when they go out of scope at the  exit of the function. Therefore they are not available to be shown. What you need to do is create the widgets with `new` and have them managed by the parent widget. The gtkmm book describes more on widget management. https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-memory-widgets.html.en

This is a corrected version of your function `test()`.

```
void test() {
    Gtk::Label *other = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Label("other"));
    Gtk::Box *otherbox = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Box());
    otherbox->pack_start(*other);
    Gtk::ListBoxRow *otherrow = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::ListBoxRow());
    otherrow->add(*otherbox);
    listbox->append(*otherrow);
}
```

Comment: I think the whole `Gtk::Box` is not even needed. You can directly add a label to a ListBoxRow.